# DeSerialize From XML By LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, serialization, deserialization

So, I have XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RailwayStations>
  <RailwayStation />
  <RailwayStationName>Verdansk</RailwayStationName>
  <RailwayStationCountOfWays>10</RailwayStationCountOfWays>
  <RailwayStationCountOfLuggageRooms>3</RailwayStationCountOfLuggageRooms>
  <RailwayStationLuggageRoomHeight>10</RailwayStationLuggageRoomHeight>
  <RailwayStationLuggageRoomWidth>20</RailwayStationLuggageRoomWidth>
  <RailwayStationLuggageRoomDepth>30</RailwayStationLuggageRoomDepth>
  <RailwayStationLuggageRoomHeight>11</RailwayStationLuggageRoomHeight>
  <RailwayStationLuggageRoomWidth>21</RailwayStationLuggageRoomWidth>
  <RailwayStationLuggageRoomDepth>31</RailwayStationLuggageRoomDepth>
  <RailwayStationLuggageRoomHeight>12</RailwayStationLuggageRoomHeight>
  <RailwayStationLuggageRoomWidth>22</RailwayStationLuggageRoomWidth>
  <RailwayStationLuggageRoomDepth>32</RailwayStationLuggageRoomDepth>
</RailwayStations>
```

And, I want to read from it. My code below returns null to all fields

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

            var obj = from xElement in xDoc.Element("RailwayStations")?.Elements("RailwayStation")
                select new RailwayStation()
                {
                    RailwayStationName = xElement.Element("RailwayStationName")?.Value,
                    RailwayStationCountOfWays = Convert.ToInt32(xElement.Element("RailwayStationCountOfWays")?.Value),
                    RailwayStationCountOfLuggageRooms =
                        Convert.ToInt32(xElement.Element("RailwayStationCountOfLuggageRooms")?.Value),
                    
                    LuggageRooms = (from element in xDoc.Element("RailwayStations")?.Elements("RailwayStation")
                        select new LuggageRoom()
                        {
                            _luggageRoomHeight = Convert.ToInt32(element.Element("RailwayStationLuggageRoomHeight")?.Value),
                            _luggageRoomWidth = Convert.ToInt32(element.Element("RailwayStationLuggageRoomHeight")?.Value),
                            _luggageRoomDepth = Convert.ToInt32(element.Element("RailwayStationLuggageRoomHeight")?.Value),
                        }).ToList()
                };
            return obj;
```

Any suggestions? About XML File - it created by self-made method, where I add `XElements` to `XDocument` and save it.

Comment: Why are you searching for elements _inside_ of `RailwayStation`? That element doesn't have any children, only siblings.

Comment: Better question, why doesn't `RailwayStation` have any children? With the node names chosen, why there are other children nodes from `RailwayStations` besides `RailwayStation`?

Comment: @gunr2171, new to serialization. In examples, which I found, constructions like that one.

Comment: @gunr2171, I think I got you.

Comment: The xml looks like it is not properly formed, fix your XML and the code will more likely work

Comment: @gnur2171, @Chris Schaller. Thanks a lot! Yea, my XML File was creating not properly, cause I forgot about index of ```RailwayStation``` where I must put my variables. I fixed it, and it start works properly.

Comment: You should consider using standard xml serialization here instead of XLinq, given that the class you are deserializing into looks like it matches the schema without need of transformation. Fluent deserialization is useful for anonymous types or when the desired output type is different the the XML schema. Using standard XML Serialization would make the _serialization output_ and _de-serialization_  consistent, you would have avoided these issues altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the expectation in your code, it looks like your XML is not well-formed, this is what your code is expecting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RailwayStations>
  <RailwayStation>
    <RailwayStationName>Verdansk</RailwayStationName>
    <RailwayStationCountOfWays>10</RailwayStationCountOfWays>
    <RailwayStationCountOfLuggageRooms>3</RailwayStationCountOfLuggageRooms>
    <LuggageRooms>
      <LuggageRoom>
        <RailwayStationLuggageRoomHeight>10</RailwayStationLuggageRoomHeight>
        <RailwayStationLuggageRoomWidth>20</RailwayStationLuggageRoomWidth>
        <RailwayStationLuggageRoomDepth>30</RailwayStationLuggageRoomDepth>          
      </LuggageRoom>
      <LuggageRoom>
        <RailwayStationLuggageRoomHeight>11</RailwayStationLuggageRoomHeight>
        <RailwayStationLuggageRoomWidth>21</RailwayStationLuggageRoomWidth>
        <RailwayStationLuggageRoomDepth>31</RailwayStationLuggageRoomDepth>         
      </LuggageRoom>
      <LuggageRoom>
        <RailwayStationLuggageRoomHeight>12</RailwayStationLuggageRoomHeight>
        <RailwayStationLuggageRoomWidth>22</RailwayStationLuggageRoomWidth>
        <RailwayStationLuggageRoomDepth>32</RailwayStationLuggageRoomDepth>       
      </LuggageRoom>
    </LuggageRooms>
  </RailwayStation>
  <RailwayStation>
    <RailwayStationName>Number 2</RailwayStationName>
    <RailwayStationCountOfWays>8</RailwayStationCountOfWays>
    <RailwayStationCountOfLuggageRooms>1</RailwayStationCountOfLuggageRooms>
    <LuggageRooms>
      <LuggageRoom>
        <RailwayStationLuggageRoomHeight>12</RailwayStationLuggageRoomHeight>
        <RailwayStationLuggageRoomWidth>22</RailwayStationLuggageRoomWidth>
        <RailwayStationLuggageRoomDepth>32</RailwayStationLuggageRoomDepth>          
      </LuggageRoom>
    </LuggageRooms>
  </RailwayStation>
</RailwayStations>
```

Notice now that `RailwayStations` (plural) now has multiple child elements called `RailwayStation`. The same then goes for the Luggage rooms, the code is actually making the wrong assumption for these anyway, but the data should be structured so that each luggage room is contained within an outer element, in this example I called it `LuggageRooms`

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
var obj = from xElement in xDoc.Element("RailwayStations")?.Elements("RailwayStation")
          select new RailwayStation()
          {
              RailwayStationName = xElement.Element("RailwayStationName")?.Value,
              RailwayStationCountOfWays = Convert.ToInt32(xElement.Element("RailwayStationCountOfWays")?.Value),
              RailwayStationCountOfLuggageRooms =
                Convert.ToInt32(xElement.Element("RailwayStationCountOfLuggageRooms")?.Value),
            
              LuggageRooms = (from element in xElement.Elements("LuggageRooms")
                select new LuggageRoom()
                {
                    _luggageRoomHeight = Convert.ToInt32(element.Element("RailwayStationLuggageRoomHeight")?.Value),
                    _luggageRoomWidth = Convert.ToInt32(element.Element("RailwayStationLuggageRoomWidth")?.Value),
                    _luggageRoomDepth = Convert.ToInt32(element.Element("RailwayStationLuggageRoomDepth")?.Value),
                }).ToList()
          };
return obj;
```

It looks like you have an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) here, if you are constructing the XML as well, please check the logic in there to make sure that it makes sense.

If you are constructing this XML, then consider a schema with simpler named elements:

```
 <RailwayStation>
   <Name>Number 2</Name>
   <CountOfWays>8</CountOfWays>
   <CountOfLuggageRooms>1</CountOfLuggageRooms>
   <LuggageRooms>
     <LuggageRoom>
       <Height>12</Height>
       <Width>22</Width>
       <Depth>32</Depth>          
     </LuggageRoom>
   </LuggageRooms>
 </RailwayStation>
```

Then your code could be something like this:

```
 var xDoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
 var obj = from xElement in xDoc.Element("RailwayStations")?.Elements("RailwayStation")
           select new RailwayStation()
           {
               Name = xElement.Element("Name")?.Value,
               CountOfWays = Convert.ToInt32(xElement.Element("CountOfWays")?.Value),
               CountOfLuggageRooms = Convert.ToInt32(xElement.Element("CountOfLuggageRooms")?.Value),
             
               LuggageRooms = (from element in xElement.Elements("LuggageRooms")
                 select new LuggageRoom()
                 {
                     Height = Convert.ToInt32(element.Element("Height")?.Value),
                     Width = Convert.ToInt32(element.Element("Width")?.Value),
                     Depth = Convert.ToInt32(element.Element("Depth")?.Value),
                 }).ToList()
           };
 return obj;
```

I realize this is a significant structure change, but it will simplify all future processing and reduce the bytes going across the wire.